# How to Handle the Back and Foward Buttons of the Web browser on flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web

I am working on a flutter web project and I am using AutoRoute ( https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)  for my routing. I am facing this challenge, trying to handle the use of the browser Back and Forward arrow buttons.

A scenario is : After login page I send the user to a homepage. I want to prevent the user from coming back to the Login page when he/she uses the Back Arrow of the browser.
Also I want to prevent the user from going straight to the home page without login by using the route url.

I have tried WillPopScope and I could not achieved my target on the web... I know that works very fine for me on mobile but not working on the web.